# Angularjs POST method 405 issue

Tags: angularjs

In my sample application GET & POST are working if I'm using localhost, if I replace with system name POST is not working. I'm seeing below errors.

IE: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load htp//machinename/services.svc/api/scenarios/add. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Messages:

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://vijayakatta/HelloService/HelloService.svc/PostData required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
File: localhost:31284

SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://vijayakatta/HelloService/HelloService.svc/PostData required CORS preflight.
File: localhost:31284
```

Error:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
File: localhost:31284
```

Angularjs:

```
   this.postData = function (param) {
        return $http.post("http://vbr/HelloService/HelloService.svc/PostData", param)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Success: "+param)
        })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("Error: "+status);
                });
    };
```

webapi:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/PostData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponseData PostData(RequestData data);
```

Server web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: did you find the solution. Facing the exact same issue